# when is drawMapRect called besides for setNeedsDisplayInMapRect?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I'm following the bread crumbs sample code provided by apple to draw a line behind a the user's location. Everything works great except when you zoom in far enough, drawMapRect stops getting called even though I'm calling setNeedsDisplayInMapRect every time a new location.

The weird thing is that I've even commented out the only place in the whole program that I call setNeedsDisplayInMapRect and when you are zoomed out it still calls drawMapRect for every new location, however if you zoom in it stops.

strange...

Comment: My guess - if you're at full zoom, and there's no new map-images to load, the mapview doesn't need to 'layoutSubviews', it just stretches the current content view.